# JDBC tells unable to find column

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I want to test some of my JPA algorithm in a separate main test file.

What I intend to do:
I send a SQL Statement from JAVA to MySQL5.1 server and want result back in ArrayList. As error information i get the column "zip" was not found

```
java.sql.SQLException: Column 'zip' not found.
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1055)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:956)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:926)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.findColumn(ResultSetImpl.java:1093)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.getString(ResultSetImpl.java:5488)
    at de.telekom.umkreissuche.SQLConnect.exportSQLResult(SQLConnect.java:82)
    at de.telekom.umkreissuche.SQLConnect.sendSQLStatement(SQLConnect.java:66)
    at de.telekom.umkreissuche.Testing.main(Testing.java:48)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at de.telekom.umkreissuche.Testing.main(Testing.java:59)
```

, but in my SQL statements im not selecting something like "zip".

SQL-File:

```
SELECT 
    d.`Web-Adresse` "Link zur Ausschreibung im Intranet"
,   d.`Ausschreibungsnr.`
,   d.`Stellenbezeichnung`
,   d.`Ausschreibende Einheit`
,   d.`Standort`
,   d.`PLZ RASt` "*PLZ"
,   DATE_FORMAT(d.`Ausschreibungsende`, "%d.%m.%Y") "Ausschreibungsende"
,   d.`Zuordnung Besoldungsgruppen` "*Besoldungsgruppe"
,   d.`Bewertung lt. Ausschreibung` "*Vergütungsgruppe"
FROM wicirclesearch.`zc_data` d
WHERE `PLZ RASt` in (:plz)
-- WHERE `PLZ RASt` in ('64289')
;
```

What i do in Java Main:

```
xml = new XMLConfigProperties("C:\\Users\\A22548675\\workspace\\umkreissuche-war\\WebContent\\data\\config\\dbMySQL.xml");
activeFilepath = new File("C:\\Users\\A22548675\\workspace\\umkreissuche-war\\WebContent\\data\\config\\mysql_plz.sql");

Map<String, String> token = new HashMap<String, String>();
token.put(":plz", "'64289'");

try {
    // create a temporary SQL file
    setTmpFileForReplacer(activeFilepath.getAbsolutePath());
    // set search tokens into SQL file
    fileTokenReplacer(activeFilepath.getAbsolutePath(), token);

    // start sql connect with XML config params
    con = new SQLConnect(xml.getProperty("jdbc.url"), xml.getProperty("jdbc.user"), xml.getProperty("jdbc.password"), xml.getProperty("jdbc.driver"));
    // use and send modified SQL file as SQL query
    testResultSQL = con.sendSQLStatement(activeFilepath.getAbsolutePath());
    System.out.println(testResultSQL.toString());
    // close SQL connection
    con.getConnection().close();
} catch (Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();}
finally{
    // recover SQL file from temporary one (temporary file delete)
    resetFileFromTmpFile(activeFilepath.getAbsolutePath());
}

// if SQL query result empty: aboard the routine and give message to webspace
if(testResultSQL.isEmpty() || testResultSQL == null){
    System.out.println("Result is leer");
}
else{
    int i = 0;
    for(ArrayList<String> liste: testResultSQL){
        System.out.print("Row "+i+": [");
        for(String e: liste){
            System.out.print(e+", ");
        }
        System.out.println("]");
        i++;
    }
}
```

---

My Question was:
Why i get these error code with not existing selected column?
Is it a bug perhaps? Or I have a syntax error?

What was my fault?
It was really mine. I don't realize my export SQL Result function, which was not modified by me.

Here is the function:

```
/**
 * Export the SQL results
 * @param resultSet {@link java.sql.ResultSet}
 * @return {@link ArrayList<ArrayList>} with {@link java.lang.String}
 * @throws SQLException
 */
private ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> exportSQLResult(ResultSet resultSet) throws SQLException{
    ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> results = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
    ArrayList<String> tmpLine;
    resultSet.beforeFirst();

    while(resultSet.next()){
        tmpLine = new ArrayList<String>();
        tmpLine.add(resultSet.getString("zip"));
        tmpLine.add(resultSet.getString("distance"));
        results.add(tmpLine);
    }
    return results;
}
```

What I do to resolve my problem:
I wanna change my method. I go away from direct selecting and wanna use only iterates.

Thank you for your help and rescue my day.

Comment: you're doing resultSet.getString('zip') in de.telekom.umkreissuche.SQLConnect.exportSQLResult(SQLConnect.java:82) but there is no zip column in result set

Comment: The method giving the error, as noted above, is `exportSQLResult`, which you are not showing... Edit your question and add this method please.

Comment: Thx @KonstantinV.Salikhov, you are right. *facepalm*... I need drink a coffee, i didn't realize my export function and forget her. *Modify Question with missing parts and solution

Comment: The problem was solved? Post the solution as an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is solved, yes.

It was my fault and I changed the problem function: (see request)

```
/**
 * Export the SQL results
 * @param resultSet {@link java.sql.ResultSet}
 * @return {@link ArrayList<ArrayList>} with {@link java.lang.String}
 * @throws SQLException
 */
private ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> exportSQLResult(ResultSet resultSet) throws SQLException{
    ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> results = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
    ArrayList<String> tmpLine;
    resultSet.beforeFirst();
    ResultSetMetaData md = resultSet.getMetaData();
    int cols = md.getColumnCount();

    tmpLine = new ArrayList<String>();
    for(int i=1; i<=cols; ++i){
        tmpLine.add(md.getColumnLabel(i));
    }
    results.add(tmpLine);

    while(resultSet.next()){
        tmpLine = new ArrayList<String>();
        for(int i=1; i<=cols; ++i){
            tmpLine.add(resultSet.getString(i));
        }
        results.add(tmpLine);
    }
    return results;
}
```